# python munkres.py cost matrix

Tags: python

is it possible to allow munkres.py to accept a cost matrix that have more row than column? From it's code shown in github, it seems like it will only pad the row, when the cost matrix have more column than row.

Comment: What is `mukres.py`?

Comment: it's one of the python package in [pypi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/munkres/), it's a Hungarian algorithm library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works either way. The source for the padding function is [here](https://github.com/bmc/munkres/blob/master/munkres.py#L331-L365).

You can verify it works both ways with this code:

```
>>> m = Munkres()
# 4 rows, 3 columns
>>> matrix = [[11, 12, 13], [21, 22, 23], [31, 32, 33], [41, 42, 43]]
>>> m.pad_matrix(matrix)
[[11, 12, 13, 0], [21, 22, 23, 0], [31, 32, 33, 0], [41, 42, 43, 0]]

# 3 rows, 4 columns
>>> matrix = [[11, 12, 13, 14], [21, 22, 23, 24], [31, 32, 33, 34]]
>>> m.pad_matrix(matrix)
[[11, 12, 13, 14], [21, 22, 23, 24], [31, 32, 33, 34], [0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Comment: thank you, it turns out that I'm passing a numpy array instead of a matrix, that's why its not working for me